# How do I exit BASH while loop using modulus operator?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

So practically for my assignment I need to break out of a true while loop when the user inputs a number that gives a modulus remainder of 0, ex: (25 % 5 = 0 **break loop**) Where in my attempt below have I gone wrong?

```
while true
do
    echo "Please input anything here: "
    read INPUT

    if [ `expr $INPUT % 5` -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "you entered wrong"
    else
        echo "you entered right"
        break
fi
done
```

Comment: If the assignment specifies `bash`, then you might consider using its built-in arithmetic expansion syntax e.g. `((  INPUT % 5 == 0 ))`

Comment: the loop does not end when entering 25 @steeldriver

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the `break` from the `else` part to the `if` part:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    echo "Please input anything here: "
    read INPUT

    if [ `expr $INPUT % 5` -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "you entered wrong"
        break
    else
        echo "you entered right"
    fi
done
```

Comment: this doesn't work, when I enter 40 the code exits

Comment: @RooseveltMendieta Isn't it what you want? ***I need to break out of a true while loop when the user inputs a number that gives a modulus remainder of 0***. 40%5 is also 0.

Comment: @Kulfy i was thinking of division in my head instead of modulus, how embarrassing lol yes this solution in fact does work and is exactly what I needed.  I need to go to sleep i've been up to late working on this assignment.

Comment: @RooseveltMendieta It seems that you changed the original code in your question. So, PerlDuck might need to modify explanation of the answer.

Comment: i version controlled the code back to it's original state @Kulfy

Answer (score 5):

It works for me according to @steeldriver's tips,

- make sure you use `bash`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  ```
- use the bash syntax for arithmetic evaluation

  ```
  ((...))
  ```

Otherwise the shellscript can remain the same,

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    echo "Please input anything here: "
    read INPUT

    if (( INPUT % 5 == 0 )) ; then
        echo "you entered right"
        break
    else
        echo "you entered wrong"
    fi
done
```

Edit: You have modified the question. This answer corresponds to a previous version of the question. (It is not clear to me, if you want to break the loop, when there is no remainder or when there is a remainder.)

Answer (score 4):

Since this is `bash` script we're talking about, you may want to use `read -p` and arithmetic evaluation `((...))`

```
$ while read -p "Enter number:" input ; do (( input%5 == 0 )) && { echo "Wrong"; break;} || echo "alright"; done
Enter number:11
alright
Enter number:7
alright
Enter number:10
Wrong
```

Portably, you might want to use `[` aka `test`

```
$ [ $((25%5)) -eq 0 ]  && echo "Zero"
Zero
$ [ $((26%5)) -eq 0 ]  && echo "Zero"
$
```